# Polynomial Regression over multiple predictors in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm

How can I fit a Polynomial Regression over all the dataframe's variables? It it were a linear regression, I would do:

```
lm.fit = lm(response~., data=dataset, subset=train)
```

but if I want a 2-nd (or higher) grade fit, I cannot use `poly()` as follows:

```
lm.fit = lm(reads_avg~poly(., i), data=dataset, subset=train)
```

In particular, poly doesn't seem to accept the point (`.`) as input.

Comment: You probably want to use `optim()` to fit an polynomial equation.

Comment: you can try something like this `lm(response~poly(x=as.matrix(dataset[, -1]), degree = 2, raw=TRUE), data=dataset)`. But be careful, `poly` adds the interactions between variables.

Comment: I have been trying with your suggestion but, being dataset a data.frame, `lm(response~poly(x=dataset[, -1]), degree = 2, raw=TRUE), data=dataset)`  it returns "non-numeric argument to binary operator". 
It works only if I select a single predictor ( e.g. `lm(response~poly(x=dataset[,2]), degree = 2, raw=TRUE), data=dataset)`

Comment: have you looked at glmulti?  (http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/2/20/model-selection-drug.html)